# html, css and js acordion when clicked on a card

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to achieve same as it is on the image.
when i click on a specific card, a card content is opened below the same card with width of 100%. Atm i am achieving this with position absolute on the card content and calculating how many content boxes does a card have, but i think i am doing the complex way of populating the card content, because what if i want to show the card content if the screen is for mobile phones, i have to make another calculation then.
Does anybody knows simpler and more dynamic solution achieving this ?

[image: example image]

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const cardContent = document.querySelectorAll('.card-content');

function accordion(e){
  if(!this.classList.contains('active')) {
    closeOthers();
    this.classList.add('active');
    console.log(this)
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('active')
  }
};

function closeOthers() {
    for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        card[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
};

for(i = 0; i < card.length; i++ ){
    card[i].addEventListener('click', accordion);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
/*   width: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.card-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  bottom: -200px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card.active .card-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    CARD1
    <div class="card-content">CARD 1 CONTENT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    CARD2
    <div class="card-content">CARD 2 CONTENT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    CARD3
    <div class="card-content">CARD 3 CONTENT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    CARD4
    <div class="card-content">CARD 4 CONTENT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">CARD5</div>
  <div class="card">CARD6</div>
  <div class="card">CARD7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pleae show us relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: okay, i wrote some code ..

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve but I'll give it a shot. Firstly, the way you've set it, you'll have a problem with overflow on the x axis. If this is your goal, I guess your code will do.

If you want things to be a bit more reasonable, I'd structure it as a grid and manipulate the grid-column value for the green rectangle (in JS, get the DOM element and redefine it in a function or whatever). This way you'd get proper-alignment and less calculations. You can still make it go outside the grid container by using a huge row-gap and placing it there with absolute positioning and a JS function to move it around. Or you can keep it as full width and simply change the content. It would be far more reasonable.

It wouldn't be great for mobile (screen size issues) but you could redefine the grid (make it 1 column and work you way down). Check out the code snippet I've attached and take it from there if it's what you had in mind.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
}

.content-display {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  /*grid-column: 2/4; - for the second card */
  /*grid-column: 3/4; - for the third card */
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-display"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-display"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <p>Card 7</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```